# How to capture screen application to .jpg and post it on wall

Tags: ajax, facebook

now i'm making application for facebook with javascript.but I don't know method to change my screen application to .jpg file.
So,I would like to know how to change my application and post it

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the screenshot done client side, however you can grab the HTML code of the page being viewed and AJAX it up to your server, have your server component transform that HTML into an image.

1. Use this to get the HTML content of the page at the moment they want the screen capture `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;`
2. AJAX the HTML to your server
3. Have your server transform that HTML into an image (depending upon server-side technology you're using, there are solutions to this) (eg http://www.converthtmltoimage.com/)
4. two choice, store the image on your server to be the permanent place sending back the new URL for the image, or send the content back to the client.
5. Have the client HTTP Post the image content to Facebook for the post, or reference the URL

It's a big project, but I commend you for tackling something like this.